# Solved Why I don't get result after bluetoothctl devices?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, bluetoothctl

when I use bluetoothctl with commands in the shell:
$ bluetoothctl power on
$ bluetoothctl scan on
$ bluetoothctl devices

or as bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                 
bluetoothctl power on
bluetoothctl discoverable on
bluetoothctl scan on
wait
bluetoothctl devices
bluetoothctl quit
exit 0
```

I don't get the result, but when I enter the bluetoothctl panel, I usually get results about devices, how do I get the result in both cases?

I found that if I open bluetooth setting panel I get result but that is not the solution

Comment: does `man bluetoothctl` give you any new info? Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot that solve my problem :) , I found a timeout option

Comment: many `man` pages are written at an expert level. You're lucky you could find your answer, BUT as far as solving problems `man progName` is the first place to look, you may luck out. Some programs also support documentation in the `.info` format, and generally those documents are a little more end-user focused. So try `info progName` to see what else is available. (Some systems don't include `info` in a base install, so you'll have to do some research on your particlar OS to see if it is available to install). Glad that helped. Good luck!